# Getting a relation between two Riemannian connections given a Riemannian submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $p: \left( \tilde{M}, \tilde{g} \right) \rightarrow \left( M, g \right)$ be a Riemannian subnersion. Let $\tilde{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ be the Riemannian connections on $\tilde{M}$ and $M$. Then, for any vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$, we have
> $$\tilde{\nabla}_{\tilde{X}} \tilde{Y} = \tilde{\nabla_X Y} + \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \tilde{X}, \tilde{Y} \right]^V,$$
> where $\tilde{X}$ denotes the horizontal lift of $X$, and $X^V$ denotes the vertical component of $X \in T(\tilde{M})$.

For this, I have already proved the following:

1. $\tilde{g} \left( \tilde{X}, \tilde{Y} \right) = g \left( X, Y \right)$.
2. $\left[ \tilde{X}, \tilde{Y} \right]^H = \tilde{\left[ X, Y \right]}$.
3. Whenever $W$ is vertical, $\left[ \tilde{X}, W \right]$ is vertical.

I want to use these facts in the proof of the result. However, I am unable to do so. This is an exercise problem in the book "Riemannian manifolds: An Introduciton to Curvature" by John M Lee. The author gives a hint that we should compute $\tilde{g} \left( \tilde{\nabla}_{\tilde{X}} \tilde{Y}, \tilde{Z} \right)$ and $\tilde{g} \left( \tilde{\nabla}_{\tilde{X}} \tilde{Y}, W \right)$ for any vertical field $W$ on $\tilde{M}$.

I do not understand how these computations will help in determining the result?

Comment: You are right! It doesn't. I meant to write something else but I skipped a few steps and mixed them. I have made the corrections.